# in batch copy the file name but not file extention

Tags: file, batch-file, replace, save, findandmodify

So i am converting excel files into a .txt files using vbs, and the input file name needs to be the same as the output file name with the changed file extension obviously. Whats making this so hard is the fact that I using this as basically a file converter so the names of the files will be random.

The way I load the input file is by is using the %1 command and just pass in the input file after I call the batch like this.NOTE: the .xlsx can be changed to any .xlsx file that i need to convert.

```
C:\tabdim>conversion_batch_file.bat **C:\tabdim\2160707.xlsx**
```

In the batch file (C:\tabdim\conversion_batch_file.bat) Note: the rest of the sql has been replaced with x's.

```
%windir%\SysWow64\wscript.exe C:\tabdim\combined.vbs **%1**
sqlcmd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
bcp xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "**C:\tabdim\20160707.txt**" xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
sqlcmd - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If there was any way to do something like this

```
"%1- last 4 characters+".txt""
```

I know that is totally wrong syntax, I'm just kind of using words to describe kind of what I'm trying to have happen.

Comment: You are looking for `%~n1` -- type `call /?` into a command prompt window to find out which `~` modifiers exist...

Comment: @Sonican You should really go back and accept some of the answer to your posts......